# Validate user input of comma separated coordinates with regex-based pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, string, input

I have a problem where the user can input any number of (x,y) co-ordinates within parentheses. For example, 
User A can input `(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)`

```
User B : (1,1)
User C : (3,2) (5,5) (6,1)
```

I want a generic pattern matching to check if the input entered by the user is valid. Input is valid only if it follows the above format. That is, `(x,y)\s(a,b)\s(c,d)`. I am new to regex matching and I tried like `(\\(\d,\d\\)\s){1,}`. This does not seem to work. Also, space should not be there after the last co-ordinate entry. Can someone help me how to get this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your coordinates always single-digit integer numbers?

Comment: You're on the right track. You'll want to escape your parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I included support for multi-digit numbers, just in case:

```
pattern = r"(\(\d+,\d+\)\s)*\(\d+,\d+\)$"
re.match(pattern, "(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)")
#<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 17), match='(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)'>
re.match(pattern, "(1,1)")
#<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='(1,1)'>
re.match(pattern, "(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) ") # no match
re.match(pattern, "(1,1) (1,2)(1,3)") # no match
```

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Not after I changed '+' to '*'.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to validate the whole input, I'd suggest the use of [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

```
>>> pattern = re.compile('(\(\d+,\d+\)\s*)+$')    
>>> def isValid(string):
...     return bool(pattern.match(string.strip()))
... 
>>> string = '(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)'
>>> isValid(string)
True
```

Either the whole string matches, or nothing matches. By default, `re.match` starts from the beginning, and will return a `match` object if the string is valid, or `None` otherwise. The `bool` result will be used to evaluate the truthiness of this expression.

Note that the whitespace character has been made optional to simplify the expression. if you want a strict matching, I recommend looking at [DYZ' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354458/4909087).

---

**Regex Details**

```
(        # capturing group 
    \(       # opening paren 
    \d+      # 1 or more digits
    ,        # comma
    \d+      
    \)       # closing paren
    \s*      # 0 or more whitespace chars
)+       # specify repeat 1 or more times
$        # end of string
```

Comment: The space between the groups is not optional.

Comment: ...But the space at the end should not match.

Comment: @DYZ In that case, your pattern is correct. I've added a note to that. Thanks for pointing it out! (upvoted it too)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

s = "(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)"
if re.findall("(\(\d+,\d+\)\s)|(\(\d+,\d+\)$)", s):
   pass
```

Comment: I think you want to change `\d` to `\d+` since there should be 1 or more digits.  You may also want to allow optional whitespace before and after digits.